# Showing one image after other using submit action PHP

Tags: php, image, action

I am reading images from the directory 'images' which contains several folders with images. I want to show every image in a div and with the checkbox to decide if it is fashion or not fashion. I am using the following code in order to read files from directory and showing them in browser. The divs is one after other:

```
<?php
function listFolderFiles($dir){
 $html = '';
 // Init the session if it did not start yet
 if(session_id() == '') session_start();
 $html .= '<ol>';
 foreach(new DirectoryIterator($dir) as $folder){
    if(!$folder->isDot()){
        if($folder->isDir()){
            // $html .= '<li>';
            $user = $dir . '/' . $folder;
            foreach (new DirectoryIterator($user) as $file) {
                if($file != '.' && $file != '..'){  
                    $image = $user . '/' . $file;
                    // Check the pictures URLs in the session
                    if(isset($_SESSION['pictures']) && is_array($_SESSION['pictures'])){
                        // Check if this image was already served
                        if(in_array($image, $_SESSION['pictures'])){
                            // Skip this image
                            continue;
                        }
                    } else {
                        // Create the session variable
                        $_SESSION['pictures'] = array();
                    }
                    // Add this image URL to the session
                    $_SESSION['pictures'][] = $image;
                    // Build the form
                    //echo $image, "</br>";
                    $html .= '  
                                <style>
                                    form{
                                            font-size: 150%;
                                            font-family: "Courier New", Monospace;
                                            display: inline-block;
                                            align: middle;
                                            text-align: center;
                                            font-weight: bold;
                                        }

                                </style>

                                <form class = "form" action="' . action($image) . '" method="post">
                                    <div>
                                        <img src="' . $image . '"  alt="" />
                                    </div>
                                    <label for="C1">FASHION</label>
                                    <input  id="fashion" type="radio" name="fashion" id="C1" value="fashion" />

                                    <label for="C2"> NON FASHION </label>
                                    <input id="nfashion" type="radio" name="nfashion" id="C2" value="nfashion" />

                                    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
                                </form>';
                    // Show one image at a time
                    // Break the loop
                    break 2;
                }   
           }
           // $html .= '</li>';
        }
    }
}
$html .= '</ol>';
return $html;
}
//##### Action function

function action($img){

  $myfile = fopen("annotation.txt", "a");

    if (isset($_POST['fashion'])) {
        fwrite($myfile, $img." -- fashion\n");
        // echo '<br />' . 'fashion image';
    }
    else{
        fwrite($myfile, $img." -- nonFashion\n");
        // echo '<br />' . ' The  submit button was pressed<br />';
    }
}

echo listFolderFiles('images//');
?>
```

When I make call of action($image) from inside form tag, I noticed, that a default value of submit it is parsed to the function, thus it stores the name of the image with the default value and the chosen value for the first image it is parsed to the second image, the chosen value of the second image it is stored to the file with the third image and so on. When I make call in side input submit tag it began storing to the file from the second image with the value of the first one and so on. I couldn't manage to have stored to the file the correct correspondence between the image and the chosen value. Where should I make call of the action function in order to do it properly?

EDIT:When I make the call inside the form, action function it is called immediately before the user press the submit button. How can I call exactly my function when the form is submitted? I tried to use  `if(strtoupper($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) === 'POST') {}`:

```
if(strtoupper($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) === 'POST') {

                        action($image);
}
```

I add the above code before the html tag, however, I am getting the same results as in the case I put action function inside submit input tag.  Any idea how to parse the right image to write value?

Comment: Lots of possibility, either you use something client side like JQuery, either you modify your server to take an "ID" or "counter" parameter to only get the good image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to break the loop every time you show one image. Also, you need to save the image URLs to avoid showing the same image more than once.
I'm using a Session to save the image URLs, but you can use a Cookie, a database etc.

Here's the code:

```
<?php
function listFolderFiles($dir){
    $html = '';
    // Init the session if it did not start yet
    if(session_id() == '') session_start();
    $html .= '<ol>';
    foreach(new DirectoryIterator($dir) as $folder){
        if(!$folder->isDot()){
            if($folder->isDir()){
                $html .= '<li>';
                $user = $dir . '/' . $folder;
                foreach (new DirectoryIterator($user) as $file) {
                    if($file != '.' && $file != '..'){  
                        $image = $user . '/' . $file;
                        // Check the pictures URLs in the session
                        if(isset($_SESSION['pictures']) && is_array($_SESSION['pictures'])){
                            // Check if this image was already served
                            if(in_array($image, $_SESSION['pictures'])){
                                // Skip this image
                                continue;
                            }
                        } else {
                            // Create the session variable
                            $_SESSION['pictures'] = array();
                        }
                        // Add this image URL to the session
                        $_SESSION['pictures'][] = $image;
                        // Build the form
                        $html .= '  <form action="action.php" method="post">
                                        <div>
                                            <img src="' . $image . '"  alt="" />
                                        </div>
                                        <label for="C1">fashion</label>
                                        <input type="checkbox" name="fashion" id="C1" value="fashion" />
                                        <label for="C2"> nfashion </label>
                                        <input type="checkbox" name="nfashion" id="C2" value="nfashion" />
                                        <input type="submit" value="submit" />
                                    </form>';
                        // Show one image at a time
                        // Break out of the 2 loops
                        break 2;
                    }   
               }
               $html .= '</li>';
            }
        }
    }
    $html .= '</ol>';
    return $html;
}
echo listFolderFiles('images');
?>
```

A good practice would be to avoid printing the HTML content within the function. It's better to print the content once it's completely ready, that's why I'm grabbing all the HTML in a variable.

I found out that you're using 2 checkboxes in the form, which means that a user can select both options and submit the form.
From the logic behind this app, I guess you should use a radio button so that the user chooses only one option.

You would have to change the form that way:

```
<label for="C1">fashion</label>
<input type="radio" name="choice" id="C1" value="fashion" />
<label for="C2"> nfashion </label>
<input type="radio" name="choice" id="C2" value="nfashion" />
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
```

Comment: Is there a way to show every time just one div and not all of them?

Comment: With the proposed code it shows me everytime all the image except those which submitted with radio button. I would like to have everytime just one image.Moreover is it possible to initialize session table?

Comment: I know that my questions are a little bit silly, however I am not familiar with php.

Comment: I edited the code. It was my mistake I used `break;` instead of `break 2;`. The latter breaks out of the 2 loops once we display one image. On another hand, there's no such thing as "session table". The session is a cookie (with extra security). It isn't a database. The whole code is written in PHP, if you're having trouble getting the basics, you should google "free PHP tutorial", you'll find a lot of tutorials and guides to learn the basics.

Comment: There is an index error in the code. For some reason, it store the first image the a default value the second image with the value of the first image and so on.

Comment: I'm not using any index. I'm filling the array using `$_SESSION['pictures'][]`. If the array doesn't exist, I create it. I'm not able to test the function properly because I don't have the whole code. I don't really understand what's wrong.

Comment: I have a action function which takes the name of the picture and the choice of the user and store it in text file. However it seem that I call action function before I gave a value to radio box. Thus it parse in the first time a default value from radio box and in the following images it parse the previous values. How can I parse to the function the actual values of radio boxes?

Comment: I tried to change the position of action function. Instead of calling it inside form I tried to calling it in input submit. It didn't affect the result.

Answer (score 2):

Use $_SESSION to remember which image you used last, so you can move onto the next when the user presses submit or you can use a hidden field which remembers the image.

I would load all the images in the folder into an array and just pass along the index number of your last used image, that way you can easily move onto the next one by doing `array[index+1]`